# Greenplum, is it possible to export CSV to remote server?

Tags: postgresql, csv, export, greenplum

I was wondering, is it possible using PostgreSQL to export data from table in Greenplum to CSV but to remote server, or transport of CSV must be done manually (or via script).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Greenplum has an external writable web table that might do the trick.

You setup a process on the remote host (GPFDIST) and configure a external writable table in green plum.

You can then treat this as a regular table and insert data into it which would reside on the remote server.

Check out:  http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4380/ref_guide/sql_commands/CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html

"*CREATE WRITABLE EXTERNAL TABLE or CREATE WRITABLE EXTERNAL WEB TABLE creates a new writable external table definition in Greenplum Database. Writable external tables are typically used for unloading data from the database into a set of files or named pipes. Writable external web tables can also be used to output data to an executable program. Writable external tables can also be used as output targets for Greenplum parallel MapReduce calculations. Once a writable external table is defined, data can be selected from database tables and inserted into the writable external table. Writable external tables only allow INSERT operations – SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE or TRUNCATE are not allowed.*"